# ROWLEX and OntologyExtractor

Tags: c#, rowlex

I have simple bussiness class in c# and want to create a RDF document.  Most of the datatype that i specify I can get OntologyExtractor to create owl schema.  How would I handle DataTime? (nullable) and System.Guid datatypes
e.g.

```
[RdfSerializable(Ontology = "http://ceoc/", HasResourceUri = true)]
public abstract class IIncident
{
    [ResourceUri]
    public abstract string Details { get; set; }
    [RdfProperty(true)]
    public abstract DateTime? log { get; set; }
    [RdfProperty(true)]
    public abstract Guid intellegience { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ROWLEX was originally built to support .NET1.1 therefore Nullable types that are introduced in .NET2.0 are not supported. However, ROWLEX is open source now, therefore contributions are welcome. Actually the implementation of Nullable support does not look very expensive.

**EDIT: [ROWLEX](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int) 2.1 has been released and it fully supports Nullable types now.**

BTW, the example code in the question will not work with the property "intellegience" because GUID is not a supported XSD value type. I assume that the Details prop was intended to be decorated as RdfProperty, while 'intellegience' (if exposed as a string) should be the ResourceUri.